# Existence of c>0 and $\delta>0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I have a problem getting the $c>0$. The problem is the following:

Let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be of class $C^1$ with $U\subset{\mathbb{R}^m}$. If $Df(x)$ is injective in all the points of a compact $K\subset{U}$, then exist $\delta>0$ and $c>0$ such that $|f(x+h)-f(x)|\geqslant c |h|$ for any $x\in{K}$ and $|h|<\delta$.

I choose $\delta$ using the fact that $U$ is open and $K\subset U$ compact, I mean for every $x\in K$, $x$ is in $U$ so there is $r_{x}>0$ such that $B(x,r_{x})\subset U$ and because $K$ is compact there is a finite number of $r_{x_i}$, so I choose $\delta=\min \lbrace{r_{x_i}} \rbrace$.

Any hint to get $c>0$?

Comment: Notice that we can rewrite this as $\left|\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\right|\geq c$ which has part of limit definition of derivative in it. Well also since derivative is continuous and $K$ is compact by extreme value theorem it achieves its inf. You could probably use this to solve your problem

Comment: I was trying something like that but the problem comes because of f' being injective, because of that f'(0)=0 then 0 is the only point in $K$ (if is in $K$) that does that. And it could be that the infimum of the function is exactly 0. My candidate for c was $c=|f'(inf)|/ \delta$, the problem is that I don't know if f'(inf)=0.

Comment: Oh I didn't even think of that case but that is true